# how to implement vertical scroll on pop-up window in android?

Tags: android

I've tried with a piece of code but it is not displaying vertical scroll bar. my code is pasted below:

```
     public void init() {
        popupButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.textview1);
        popupText = new TextView(this);
        insidePopupButton = new Button(this);
        layoutOfPopup = new LinearLayout(this);
        LinearLayout lt=new LinearLayout(this);
        view=new ScrollView(this);
        insidePopupButton.setText("OK");
        popupText.setText("This is Popup Window.press OK to dismiss   it.");
        popupText.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
        popupText.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 20);
        layoutOfPopup.setOrientation(1);
        lt.addView(popupText);
        layoutOfPopup.addView(insidePopupButton,350,35);

        layoutOfPopup.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
        view.addView(lt);
        layoutOfPopup.addView(view);
```

[image]
Thank you in advance..:)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You need to add your views in this way:

```
LinearLayout linearLayout = new LinearLayout(this);

// add all your views to linearLayout(or RelativeLayout)
linearLayout.addView(popupText);
linearLayout.addView(insidePopupButton); 

// add linearLayout to ScrollView instance
view.addView(linearLayout);

// add ScrollView instance to main layout
layoutOfPopup.addView(view);
```

ScrollView is a single element container.

Comment: Thank you kelvincer. I am getting scroll bar but 'OK' button to close pop-up is not displayed on pop-up

Comment: add your button to linearLayout

Comment: Button displayed on top of the pop-up window instead of down when I add that to main linear layout only ...I need to show my Ok button in the bottom of the pop-up window..

Comment: order matters when adding views to LinearLayout (You Have to design)

Comment: I've updated my code like above can you Please verify once and I've added screen shot too

Comment: Put this layoutOfPopup.addView(insidePopupButton,350,35) in the final part

Comment: I've tried like that too. But still I am getting the same issue..can you please spare your valuable time for me

Comment: Unless I know scrollView cannot be used in popWindows in android. If it worked for you, do let me know, I want to implement it too.

Answer (score 2):

`ScrollView` cannot be combine with `popupWindow` in android, no matter what. Sad but true.

Comment: But one can activate vertical scrolling for TextViews by calling 
        `popupText.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());`. Unfortunately I have no idea why it does not work by the usual xml code ..